# MySQL - trying to count number of times a value appears

Tags: mysql

Edit #2 - i think i figured out why using just COUNT(*) was giving me an incorrect value. i simplified this database and didn't account the factor that there are multiple rows for each 'day'... i've filled in another table to illustrate the problem better.

---

I'm new to sql and have looked at similar posts and tried GROUP BY and COUNT as suggested but I am not getting it right. I'm trying to get a total number of times a particular day appears so I can get the average of books/day if there was a sale.

```
Table - book                        Table - sale_day

+-------+---------------------+     +-------+----------+------------+
|   ID  |   Title             |     |   ID  |   Day    |  Date      |
+-------+---------------------+     +-------+----------+------------+
|     1 | Pride & Prejudice   |     |     1 | Monday   | 2016-01-02 |
|     2 | The Little Prince   |     |     2 | Tuesday  | 2016-01-03 |
|     3 | Harry Potter        |     |     3 | Monday   | 2016-01-09 |
+-------+---------------------+     +-------+----------+------------+
```

Table - book_sale

```
+------+---------+-----------+-------------+
|  ID  | Book_ID | Book_Sold | SaleDay_ID  | 
+------+---------+-----------+-------------+
|    1 |      1  |         6 | 1           |
|    2 |      2  |         3 | 1           |
|    3 |      3  |         1 | 1           |
|    4 |      1  |         2 | 1           |
|    5 |      3  |         8 | 2           |
|    6 |      1  |         3 | 3           |
|    7 |      2  |         3 | 3           |
|    8 |      1  |         6 | 1           |
|    9 |      1  |         7 | 3           |
+------+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

SQL:

```
$result = mysql_query("
          SELECT book_id, title, SUM(book_sold) AS book_sold, day,    
                 COUNT(book_sale.id) AS book_count
          FROM book_sale 
          LEFT JOIN book ON book_sale.book_id = book.id 
          LEFT JOIN sale_day ON book_sale.saleday_id = sale_day.id 
          GROUP BY title, day");
```

Output [I got the first 3 columns, I'm trying to get the value of the 4th column]:

```
+--------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
|  Book              | Total Sold |    Day      |    Count of # Days    |
+--------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
|  Pride & Prejudice |      24    |   Monday    |         2             |
|  The Little Prince |      6     |   Monday    |         2             |
|  Harry Potter      |      1     |   Monday    |         1             |
|  Harry Potter      |      8     |   Tuesday   |         1             |
+--------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

I want the number of days each day exist so I can get the average per day, IF there was a sale that day. E.g. Pride & Prejudice = 11/3 = 3.66667/Monday.

I've tried COUNT(day) but I got an incorrect value - i think it's counting the number of times 'Monday' appears, but the value shown is not dependent for each book.

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT #1 -- Everyone has been giving the same answers but i still can't get the value right so here's the rest of the code, just in case the mistake is here :(

```
while ($book_sale = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<table><tr><td>" . $book_sale['title'] . "</td><td>" .                
          $book_sale['book_sold']  . "</td><td>" . 
          $book_sale['day']  . "</td><td>" . 
          $book_sale['book_count'] . "</td></tr></table>"; 
}
```

Comment: COUNT(*) should work. I don't know what is wrong with above. It is returning the number of times each book showed up on a given day. Is that now what you are looking for?

Comment: @lrb count(*) ended up giving me a weird number which I can't guess from where, but it's a huge number, I'm thinking it is calculating the sum of the all the id's of book_sale. The database is a lot more complicated then the one I presented here and I can't seem to find the cause of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to count the number of bool_sold rows in each group. Since you've said you're joining other tables that are not shown, in order to prevent them from being counted too, you'll need to use the `distinct` keyword to count just the rows from the `book_sale` table. So use `count(distinct <primary-key-of-table>)`. Like this:

```
SELECT book_id, title, SUM(book_sold) AS book_sold, day,
    count(distinct book_sale.ID) as `Count of # Days`
    FROM book, book_sale 
    WHERE book_id = book.id  
    GROUP BY title, day
    ORDER BY `Count of # Days` desc;
```

Note: The tables, data and expected results were edited after the test case below was created. The test case applies to a previous edit of the question.

### Test Case:

```
create table book (
ID int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
Title varchar(255) not null
) engine=innodb;

create table book_sale (
ID int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
Book_ID int unsigned not null,
Book_Sold int unsigned not null,
Day varchar(255) not null,
foreign key book_sale_Book_ID_key(Book_ID) references book(ID)
) engine=innodb;

insert into book
(ID, Title)
values
(1, 'Pride & Prejudice'),
(2, 'The Little Prince'),
(3, 'Harry Potter');

insert into book_sale
(ID, Book_ID, Book_Sold, Day)
values
(1, 1, 6, 'Monday'),
(2, 2, 3, 'Monday'),
(3, 3, 1, 'Monday'),
(4, 1, 2, 'Monday'),
(5, 3, 8, 'Tuesday'),
(6, 1, 3, 'Monday'),
(7, 2, 3, 'Monday');
```

### Results:

```
mysql> SELECT book_id, title, SUM(book_sold) AS book_sold, day,
    ->     count(distinct book_sale.ID) as `Count of # Days`
    ->     FROM book, book_sale 
    ->     WHERE book_id = book.id  
    ->     GROUP BY title, day
    ->     ORDER BY `Count of # Days` desc;
+---------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+
| book_id | title             | book_sold | day     | Count of # Days |
+---------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+
|       1 | Pride & Prejudice |        11 | Monday  |               3 |
|       2 | The Little Prince |         6 | Monday  |               2 |
|       3 | Harry Potter      |         1 | Monday  |               1 |
|       3 | Harry Potter      |         8 | Tuesday |               1 |
+---------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: In this answer, I've recreated the tables and data posted in your question and exactly re-produced the desired result posted in your question. I've done the best I can with the information provided in the question and comments. You need to be *much more specific* about what "didn't work" and "get the same value" mean. What value do you get? What value do you expect?

Comment: hey thanks for the code. i figured out what was wrong, there are actually multiple records for each day so i can't use COUNT(*) as it's counting the individual records. i've updated the post so i hope you can look into it again. thanks!

Comment: Ok, now that you've mentioned that there are other tables being joined that are not shown (a critical piece of information!), I've updated my answer to add a note about the `distinct` keyword.

Comment: omg it worked thank you T_T... actually it worked with count(distinct sale_day.id) instead of book_sale but either way, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables.  One easy way is with the `on` clause:

```
SELECT b.book_id, b.title, SUM(bs.book_sold) AS book_sold,
       COUNT(*) as NumDifferentDays
FROM book b JOIN
     book_sale bs
     on b.id = bs.book_id
GROUP BY b.book_id, b.title;
```

You have one record for each day, so you just need `COUNT(*)` to find the number of days.  The key is not not include `day` in the `GROUP BY`.  To get the average, just use `AVG(bs.book_sold)`.

Comment: The OP did join the 2 tables in the original query. The OP just used the older comma separated tables and join condition in WHERE clause syntax, which is still valid.

Comment: @gordon-linoff what if i have multiple records for each day? i think this is my issue. i simplified it for SO but the real database is a lot more complicated.

Comment: @gummybearpaws . . . We are only capable of answering the questions that are actually asked.  But the answer to your question would be to use `count(distinct)`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a working query:

```
SELECT
  title AS "Book",
  SUM(book_sold) AS "Total Sold",
  day AS "Day",
  COUNT(book_sale.id) AS "Count of # Days"
FROM
  book_sale LEFT JOIN book ON book_sale.book_id = book.id
GROUP BY
  book.id, book_sale.day
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf5fa/3

Comment: hey thanks for the code. i figured out what was wrong, there are actually multiple records for each day so i can't use COUNT(*) as it's counting the individual records. i've updated the post so i hope you can look into it again. thanks!